# Redux thunk fetch return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, thunk

I'm new with `Redux Thunk` and I'm having problems with `dispatch` an action after fetching `async` call by click on button component.

**actions.js**

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

export const getPosts = (json) => {
    return {
        type: constant.GET_POSTS,
        payload: {
            data: json
        }
    }
}

export const loadPosts () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(res => {
                res.json()
            }).then(json => {
                dispatch(getPosts(json))
            })
    }
}
```

**button.js**

```
class Button extends React.Component {

    clicked(){
        console.log(this.props.loadJsonPosts()) // got undefined here
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <button onClick={this.clicked.bind(this)}>click</button>
        )
    }
}
```

**buttonContainer.js**

```
import connect from 'react-redux/lib/components/connect'
import { loadPosts } from '../actions/actions.js'
import Button from '../components/Button'

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        loadJsonPosts: () => { dispatch(loadPosts()) }
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Button)
```

**reducer.js**

```
import * as constant from '../constants/index'

let initialState = { postList: [] }

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case constant.GET_POSTS: //here i call my loadPosts action
            state = Object.assign({}, { postList: [{ post: action.data }] })
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return state
}

export default reducer
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Main from './components/Main'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware  } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import reducer from './reducers/reducer'
const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
)

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Main />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

I can't figure out why i get `undefined`, maybe I've missed something or I've wrong the approach

Comment: Did you register your reducer in rootReducer?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to return `res.json()` in actions.js for the next then block.
it should be

```
export const loadPosts () => {
return (dispatch) => {
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(res => {
            return res.json();
        }).then(json => {
            dispatch(getPosts(json))
        })
      }}
```

or you can skip the return statement by removing the blocks  by writing  `.then(res => res.json())`

Comment: You're right Vikramaditya, I've correct it but the result is the same anyway

Comment: in `mapDispatchToProps ` function you should also return the function like this `loadJsonPosts: () => { return dispatch(loadPosts()) }` and in reducer you should never assign anything to state, insteas you should simply write ``case constant.GET_POSTS:
           return Object.assign({}, { postList: [{ post: action.payload.data }] }); `

Comment: There are still some blunders i am not able to figure out, but i would suggest read the redux docs throughly once more. you are missing some basics of redux

Comment: Please have a look on this query :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49065390/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-functionevaluating-fetchurl?noredirect=1#comment85136212_49065390

Answer (score 3):

I the same issue and found that ensuring the thunk middleware was *first* in my chain when creating the redux store allowed me to access the promise I was after rather than getting `undefined`,

```
store = createStore(
            rootReducer, 
            initialState,
            applyMiddleware(thunk, otherMiddleware1, otherMiddleware2)
        );
```

Comment: This was correct in my case too. Even returning true in the action creator failed.  Moving it first now returns the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

mapDispatchToProps should be like this:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
return {
    // loadPosts instead of loadPosts()
    loadJsonPosts: () => { dispatch(loadPosts) }
} }
```