# Redux not assigning fetched array to state variable

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm fetching an array from the backend, it works, but redux is somehow not assigning the array to a variable. `products` in `initialState` is always empty and if I try to reference it in my component, it is `undefined`.

**RestActions:**

```
const receivedProducts = (products) => ({
    type: "RECEIVED_PRODUCTS",
    products
})


export function getProducts() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        return axios({
            url: '/products',
            timeout: 20000,
            method: 'get'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            let p = response.data;
            dispatch(receivedProducts(p));
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            if(error.response) {
                // DEBUGGING
                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.status);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
            }
        })
    }
};
```

I placed my `reducer` in the `store`. This is what it looks like.

**Store**

```
const initialState = {

    // KEYBOARD
    searchWord: '',

    // BASKET
    basket:[],

    // PRODUCTS
    products: []
};
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log('reducer', action);
    console.log('basket', state.basket);
    console.log('products', state.products)
    switch(action.type) {

        // REST
        case 'RECEIVED_PRODUCTS':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {products: action.products});
        ...
```

My component dynamically creates buttons based on `products` and renders them in a grid. Whenever I call `this.props.products.length`, it is undefined. This is the component:

**Buttons**

```
class ButtonsGrid extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getProducts();
    }

    addProduct = (product) => {
        this.props.onButtonPress(product);
    }

    render() {   
        const {classes} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <GridList cellHeight={50} cols={10}>
                    {this.props.list.length > 0 ? this.props.list.map(product => {
                        return (
                            <Button key={Math.random()} style={{width: '200px', border: '1px solid'}} variant="raised" color="primary" onClick={() => this.addProduct(product)}>
                                <div 
                                    style={{fontSize:'12px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', textAlign:'center'}}>
                                        {product.name}
                                </div>
                            </Button>
                        );
                    }) : ''}
                </GridList>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        basket: state.basket,
        products: state.products
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return { 
        onButtonPress: (data) => {
            let action = { type: 'PRODUCT_ADD', product: data };
            dispatch(action);
        },
        getProducts : function() {
            dispatch(getProducts());
        }
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ButtonsGrid);
```

Then it gets called in `App.js`

**App.js**

`<ButtonsGrid store={store} list={this.state.list} clicked={this.clicked}/>`

So, I can `console.log('reducer', action);` and it does print the right stuff, but I can't assign the data to `products`. I tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015721/redux-thunk-fetch-return-undefined) but it still didn't work.

The data is just two json objects.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What error do you receive?(If any)

Comment: I check `{this.props.list.length > 0 ? ...}` before rendering the buttons in the Buttons component. I get length is `undefined`. I forgot to add `products: state.products` to Buttons' `mapStateToProps` and now I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cols' of undefined
`. If I `console.log()` the products in the store, then I just get an empty array.

Comment: Okay, I am totally confused. I can log `this.props.products` successfully in `ButtonsComponent` and it prints an empty array. However if I try to map the objects to buttons in the loop, I get `undefined`. This is so confusing.

Comment: try doing `console.log(this.props)` in `ButtonsGrid` to see if `this.props.list` exists.

Comment: [`console.log(this.props)`](https://imgur.com/a/PPALi) does work. `this.props.list` was just for testing before I integrated `redux`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spread the `state` object

```
 return Object.assign({}, ...state, {
  products: [
    ...state.products,
    action.products
  ]
});
```

Comment: I am not using `combineReducers`.

Comment: Could you please console `state` in `mapStateToProps ` and shared the outut

Comment: If I try to map the objects to buttons in `ButtonsGrid` like this `{this.props.products.length > 0 ? this.props.products.map(product => {` - I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cols' of undefined
`

Comment: `return Object.assign({}, state, {products: [...state.products, action.products]});` yields the same `TypeError`.

Comment: @Claim0013 not like this. Please check EDIT.Only `state` second param

Comment: Oh sorry, I overlooked that. I did and same TypeError. It really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Okay, I was getting that `undefined` TypeError because of my ternary check. I removed it and the app stopped crashing. Although I am still not getting any objects in `products`

Comment: `return Object.assign({}, state, {products: [...this.state.products, action.products]});` WORKED! Could you elaborate why? Now I am getting `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
` if I try to add one of the fetched objects to another array like so
`return Object.assign({}, state, { basket: [...state.basket, action.product]})
` But I'll solve that myself.

Comment: @Claim0013 `[...this.state.products, action.products]` I missed it.my bad. Its way of  concat the existing and new element of the array.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time!